# How do I create a Flipbook using Operture Wordpress Content Manager?

Tags: wordpress

I have seen that Operture Wordpress content manager supports flipbook. A flipbook can be created without much coding. This is a very nice feature and want to know how I can do that.

Comment: You can find more about Operture flipbook here https://operture.com/account/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=105

Comment: Operture flipbook is interesting, everything has already been installed, no coding required. You can check it out on their site operture.com